# R/shiny user registration/authentication

Tags: r, authentication, shiny

I'm looking for a user registration/log in code template for r/shiny. It need not be secure, just a way to personalize the content on a shiny app based on previous user settings. I don't want to rely too much on server services (such as accessing cookies)

I wonder if there is something out there, or whether there are any suggestions about how to implement it.

So far I've been trying to do it myself, using a set of reactive variables (other than the input/output) on the client side, that remember the state of the session. The code became a bit ugly and I wonder if there is something simpler that I can reuse.

A link to a working example would be great as well :)

Thanks.

Comment: There is a nice blog on the topic at http://withr.me/blog/2014/01/03/authentication-of-shiny-server-application-using-a-simple-method/. There is a demo ap at http://spark.rstudio.com/withr/authentication/ user: withr pass: 12345678

Comment: @jdharrison Thanks. This solution is very similar to what I already did. It becomes more complicated if you want to add a registration component that allows adding new users, and when you actually try to make content more personal. I can complete the solution in this line of thinking, but am trying to avoid reinventing the wheel. Thanks for the links, anyway.

Answer (score 4):

I know that this question is pretty old, but I want to add answer for anyone else looking for solution nowadays.

Facing the problem like yours I'm developing a package `shiny.reglog`. It allows anonymous users to look through your app, but also allows user to register. Server-side can access the user id of the logged user for inter-session recognition.

Package is available through CRAN, for development version and more in-depth guide and examples check github: https://github.com/statismike/shiny.reglog

Answer (score 1):

http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/authentication-and-database.html -
Here the membership information is saved into membership_db through savesqlite. I think you can allow registration by adding to membship_db

Comment: But thats only helping if you have a shiny server pro version

Comment: why do you need the pro version?

Comment: The whole user authentication thing only works with shiny pro, at least that what it says if I run the code myself.